# How to include part of PHAR in PhpStorm Include path

Tags: php, phpstorm, phar, php-deployer

I'm using PhpStorm and [Deployer](https://deployer.org/) so I included `deployer.phar` in PHP Include paths to have auto-completion in `deploy.php` file. After including the whole `deployer.phar` PhpStorm complains about duplicate class definition - one coming from my app vendor directory, and second from deployer.phar vendor directory.

Is it somehow possible to configure PhpStorm Include paths so only some parts of PHAR file (ex. only the `src` directory) are included? This doesn't work:

```
/path/to/deployer.phar/src
```

nor this:

```
phar:///path/to/deployer.phar/src
```

I want to avoid installing `deployer/deployer` as composer dev package.

**EDIT**

It [seems](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-41146) that even adding single PHAR file in Include paths is kind of a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible currently. As a workaround you can unpack deployer.phar somewhere and add extracted `deployer.phar/src` to Include paths. Not convenient, but would work.